# Tokenizing for AoT compilation

Tags: angular, token, aot

I've been having some issues with the inconsistencies between the [JIT and AoT compilers](https://github.com/rangle/angular-2-aot-sandbox#current-status). The most recent error that has stumped me was `Error: Can't resolve all parameters for IndexedDBCache`. IndexedDBCache is a service that depends on a `string` parameter:

*Please note this issue also arises when I remove the 'protected' property!*

```ts
// indexeddb-cache.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class IndexedDBCache {
  constructor(protected databaseName : string) {}
}
```

I'm using a factory to provide versions of the service:

```ts
// test-api.cache.factory.ts
import { IndexedDBCache } from '../indexeddb-cache/indexeddb-cache';

export function testIndexedDBCacheFactory() { return new IndexedDBCache('test'); }

// test-api.cache.ts
import { InjectionToken, Provider } from '@angular/core';
import { IndexedDBCache } from '../indexeddb-cache/indexeddb-cache';
import { testIndexedDBCacheFactory } from './test-api.cache.factory';

export const testIndexedDBCache = new InjectionToken<IndexedDBCache>('testIndexedDBCache');

export let testIndexedDBCacheProvider : Provider = {
  provide: testIndexedDBCache,
  useFactory: testIndexedDBCacheFactory
};
```

*Note : These files have to be split according to [func-in-providers-useFactory](https://github.com/rangle/angular-2-aot-sandbox#func-in-providers-usefactory-top) and [arrow-function-exports](https://github.com/rangle/angular-2-aot-sandbox#arrow-function-exports-top) - don't ask me why =/*

Now the AoT compiler doesn't like this `string` paramter at all. I've looked into the issue but could only find reference to `OpaqueToken` (now depricated and replaced by `InjectionToken<string>`). My code would now read:

```ts
// test-api.cache.factory.ts
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import { IndexedDBCache } from '../indexeddb-cache/indexeddb-cache';

const testIndexedDBCacheFactoryToken = new InjectionToken<string>('test');
export function testIndexedDBCacheFactory() { return new IndexedDBCache(testIndexedDBCacheFactoryToken); }
```

Obviously this is not compiling as the constructor would only allow for a `string` parameter. I don't have enough knowledge about InjectionTokens or the AoT issue at hand to solve this - anyone have a suggestion for a construct that would work?

More context on my code and issue to be found at [angular/angular#17295](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17295#issuecomment-307049043).

---

Things I've tried:

1. Removing the `protected` access modifier > *Exact same error persists*
2. Removing the string parameter > *Not an option - it defines the service*
3. Replacing the string parameter in the factory with an `InjectionToken<string>` > *An InjectionToken is not a suitable parameter*

Comment: `constructor(protected databaseName : string) {}`
You cant do this, since this class is marked as @Injectable Angular will try inject that string in which it cannot do

Comment: @Toxicable It works fine when using JIT though. Is there an alternative way of setting up service factories based on a string?

Comment: if the class does not have `@Injectable()` Angular will not try inject it, this is the only way you can use the constructor

Comment: It does have `@Injectable()` and it works.. I have it running in JIT and in karma.

Comment: Running in JIT is not the same as running in AOT, so saying it works in one does not imply that it should work in the other

Comment: @Toxicable Still.. even if it doesn't work is there an alternative that does work?

Comment: Reworked my question and examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44461657/creating-aot-compatible-service-factories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a misunderstanding of the issue at hand. The classes to be factoried are not services themselves and as such do not need the `@Injectable` property. More detail to be found at [Creating AoT compatible Service Factories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44461657/creating-aot-compatible-service-factories/44495490#44495490)