# Creating AoT compatible Service Factories

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, aot

I'm trying to create a service factory for a caching service. The major requirement is that a single service can be instanced with a different string each time.

The final result will have multiple **cache** services each defined by a unique `databaseName`. Each cache can have one or more **stores** also defined by a unique `storeName`. Other services will be able to use these stores:

```
mainCache                         = new Cache('main')
  ├── userStore                   = new Store(mainCache, 'user')
  │     ├── userService
  │     └── authenticationService
  │
  └── taskStore                   = new Store(mainCache, 'task')
        └── taskService

fooCache                          = new Cache('foo')
  └── barStore                    = new Store(otherCache, 'bar')
```

My current implementations look like this:

```ts
//indexeddb-cache.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class IndexedDBCache {
  constructor(
    protected databaseName : string
  ) {}
}

// indexeddb-store.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { IndexedDBCache } from './indexeddb-cache';

@Injectable()
export class IndexedDBStore {
  constructor(
    protected database : IndexedDBCache,
    protected storeName : string
  ) {}
}
```

The services are factoried:

```ts
// test-api.cache.factory.ts
import { IndexedDBCache } from '../indexeddb-cache/indexeddb-cache';
import { IndexedDBStore } from '../indexeddb-cache/indexeddb-store';

// factory functions for FactoryProviders as exports instead of inline:
// https://github.com/rangle/angular-2-aot-sandbox#func-in-providers-usefactory-top
export function mainIndexedDBCacheFactory() { return new IndexedDBCache('main'); }
export function userIndexedDBStoreFactory(testIndexedDBCache: IndexedDBCache) { return new IndexedDBStore(testIndexedDBCache, 'user'); }
export function taskIndexedDBStoreFactory(testIndexedDBCache: IndexedDBCache) { return new IndexedDBStore(testIndexedDBCache, 'task'); }
```

And then provided:

```ts
// test-api.cache.ts
import { InjectionToken, Provider } from '@angular/core';
import { IndexedDBCache } from '../indexeddb-cache/indexeddb-cache';
import { IndexedDBStore } from '../indexeddb-cache/indexeddb-store';
import { mainIndexedDBCacheFactory,
         taskIndexedDBStoreFactory,
         userIndexedDBStoreFactory } from './test-api.cache.factory';

// Caches

export const mainIndexedDBCache = new InjectionToken<IndexedDBCache>('mainIndexedDBCache');

export let mainIndexedDBCacheProvider : Provider = {
  provide: mainIndexedDBCache,
  useFactory: mainIndexedDBCacheFactory
};

// Stores

export const userIndexedDBStore = new InjectionToken<IndexedDBStore>('userIndexedDBStore');

export let userIndexedDBStoreProvider : Provider = {
  provide: userIndexedDBStore, deps: [mainIndexedDBCache],
  useFactory: userIndexedDBStoreFactory
};

export const taskIndexedDBStore = new InjectionToken<IndexedDBStore>('taskIndexedDBStore');

export let taskIndexedDBStoreProvider : Provider = {
  provide: taskIndexedDBStore, deps: [mainIndexedDBCache],
  useFactory: taskIndexedDBStoreFactory
};
```

Declared in the main module:

```ts
// test-api-module.ts
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { mainIndexedDBCacheProvider,
         taskIndexedDBStoreProvider,
         userIndexedDBStoreProvider } from './test-api.cache';

@NgModule({
  imports: [], declarations: [], exports: []
})
export class TestAPIModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: TestAPIModule,
      providers: [
        mainIndexedDBCacheProvider,
        userIndexedDBStoreProvider,
        taskIndexedDBStoreProvider
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

And finally used in a service:

```ts
//user-service/user.service.ts
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { IndexedDBStore } from '../../indexeddb-cache/indexeddb-store';
import { userIndexedDBStore } from '../test-api.cache';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(userIndexedDBStore) protected cache : IndexedDBStore
  ) {}
}
```

Everything works fine when using JIT compilers. When I'm trying to do AoT compilation I start receiving `Warning: Can't resolve all parameters for x in y: (?). This will become an error in Angular v5.x` for the string parameters of the cache and store service.

I've detailed my issue before in this question: [Tokenizing for AoT compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44432641/tokenizing-for-aot-compilation). Now it looks like using strings as parameters for an `@Injectable()` is completely impossible with the AoT compiler. Is there any other way of creating a factory for services initialized using a string as I've described?

I've created a workable example in [this repository](https://github.com/Karasuni/angular-seed/tree/aot). Checkout the `aot` branch and `npm install` followed by `npm run build.prod.rollup.aot` should work just like that.

Comment: And what are x and y in 'x in y'?..

Comment: @estus `IndexedDBCache` and the location of `indexeddb-cache.ts`.

Comment: I'm not sure how `protected storeName : string` is supposed to work. There's no `string` provider. It isn't AoT-specific feature, I would expect it to fail in JiT too because it's just wrong. If you use `IndexedDBCache` only as `new IndexedDBCache`, it shouldn't be `Injectable`. Try to remove `Injectable` from classes that don't do DI in constructors and check if it works for you.

Comment: @estus It's worked like this in angularjs and works without fail in JIT. It even compiles in AoT in this example but presents a warning. The core idea is that I can make multiple stores from a single definition (> factory) and that multiple components can talk to the same store instance. If this is the wrong approach could you give an example of the right approach for this structure?

Comment: Angular (2 and higher) isn't AngularJS, they are oranges and apples. Just remove @Injectable from IndexedDBCache and IndexedDBStore . It isn't an injectable because constructor params aren't proper services. See this explanation for Injectable decorator https://stackoverflow.com/a/39029435/3731501

Comment: @estus Hmm.. I think I understand your point. I'll try this out now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on feedback from users @estus and @Toxicable the class that will only be instanced by a `Factory` should not be `@Injectable` itself. Removing this tag from the `IndexedDBCache` and `IndexedDBStore` classes will resolve the issue.

---

The `Factory` also has to be in the specific form

```ts
export function mainIndexedDBCacheFactory() { return new IndexedDBCache('main'); }
```

Other iterations of this definition will not work.

```ts
export const mainIndexedDBCacheFactory = function() { return new IndexedDBCache('main'); };
export let mainIndexedDBCacheFactory   = function() { return new IndexedDBCache('main'); };
export let mainIndexedDBCacheFactory   = () => new IndexedDBCache('main');
```

The [`export` prefix is required](https://github.com/rangle/angular-2-aot-sandbox#func-in-providers-usefactory-top) even if the definition is in the same file as the `Provider`.